# Is there an OpenID demo server out there?

Tags: openid

I'm doing some experiements with adding OpenID to something I'm working on, and I'd like to test out a few providers.

Is there a server out there that will go through the OpenID login process (same way that the StackOverflow group does) and tell me all the information the provider shows.

I imagine it would work like...

- I go to example.com and type in https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
- example.com bounces me to google. I log in.
- Google asks me to confirm if I allow example.com access to everything.
- Google bounces me back to example.com
- example.com tells me my OpenID, email address, anything else it's got.

Does such a thing please already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741363/openid-development-and-debugging-tools has some links to useful-looking tools...

Comment: This... http://dotnetopenauth.net/samples/v3.0/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/ is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can always setup your own: I created one using Community-ID for PHP (pretty straightforward), here's a list of servers/libraries:
http://wiki.openid.net/Run-your-own-identity-server

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what the OP wants?

Comment: The OP didn't specifically say he didn't want to setup an identity server, no. If he runs his own test identity server, it'll be trivial to see what data is exchanged during authentication, etc.